# javascript how to remove every 3rd element from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

how do i remove every 3rd element from an array?

```
var TheArray = ['h', 'e', 'z', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

How do I make this say "hello" without creating a new array?

Comment: Just to let you know, creating a new array will be about 20 times faster in this case, i.e. `newArray = []; for (i = 0; i <= TheArray.length; i += 3) newArray.push(TheArray[i]) && newArray.push(TheArray[i+1]);`

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yexqr68z/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 2; i <= TheArray.length; i += 2)
    TheArray.splice(i, 1);
```

If you want a string in the end, just use `TheArray.join("")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot you've helped me quite a bit! :)

Comment: @user2033351 You're welcome. Keep in mind that some array methods, like `splice`, `sort` and `push` modify the array while other, like `slice`, `concat`, `map` and `filter` do not.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to use the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. Here is how to remove every 3rd element using it:

```
var TheArray = ['h', 'e', 'z', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o']
TheArray = TheArray.filter(function(d, i){ return (i+1)%3 !== 0; })
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the better method now. Even shorter, using arrow functions:
`TheArray = TheArray.filter((d, i) => (i + 1) % 3)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string, don't change the array.

```
var r = '';
for (var i=0; i<TheArray.length; i++) {
   if (i%3!=2) r += TheArray[i];
}
// now r is "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var arr = ['h', 'e', 'z', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
for(var i = 2; i < arr.length; i+=2)
    arr.splice(i, 1);
console.log(arr); // outputs ['h','e','l','l','o']
```